# azure notfication hub registration time to live

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

How can I change the time to live for a registration (default = 90 days) on azure notificationhub?
I only found this article where it is mentioned:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-registration-management.md

For registration on mobile devices I use the AzureMessaging component:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-messaging

I didn't find any settings on the azure portal.

In the component-library I found the `ExpirationTime` of a `Registration` but it is readonly. The `Registration`-Class is also protected so I don't have access.

```
var registration =_hub?.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
var thisIsReadOnly = registration.ExpirationTime;
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I believe the time might be dictated by the platforms you're using to send notifications. Is there any reason why you need a longer TTL? Every time a user starts your application it is best to re-register them for push notifications I find.

Comment: Well actually I want to make the TTL shorter and not longer. Thats why I am asking. But maybe microsoft removed the possibility to change the TTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can only set the TTL for APN templates using the expiry element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
            <Tags>myTag, myOtherTag</Tags>
            <DeviceToken>{DeviceToken}</DeviceToken>
            <BodyTemplate><![CDATA[{Template for the body}]]></BodyTemplate>
            <Expiry>{Template for Expiry in }</Expiry>
        </AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription>
    </content>
</entry>
```

ref: [Create Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx)

However keep checking the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx) for updates this *may* change.